# Dual boot domain connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot, domain, windows-domain

So I have a surface computer and I'd like to dual boot Windows 10 and (another) Windows 10 on it. I know how dual booting works (enough) and have done it successfully before. 
My question is, if I join a domain in one operating system, am I on that domain in the other? I'd like one to be connected to my school domain and the other to not be connected to a domain at all. I would do this on one operating system but the domain does not allow you to leave after joining (without formatting computer). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the two operating systems are completely separate in a dual boot configuration, so all settings (including domain settings) are independent of the other.

Answer (score 0):

> if I join a domain in one operating system, am I on that domain in the other

No. Your OS joins that domain. Not your computer.